# How to increase limit for open processes and files using ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am setting up a MySQL server, and I was told to increase the `ulimit` for the number of open processes.

I ran

```
- name: "increase limit for the number of open files"
  shell: "ulimit -n 64000"
- name: "increase limit for the number of open processes"
  shell: "ulimit -u 64000"
```

on the `ansible-playbook`, but not only does it throw error "Illegal option -u", but also open files limit (-n) doesn't seem to get modified. (I ran `ulimit -n` on the server but it stays the same)

What is the recommended way of increasing these limits, and how should I do it in Ansible?

I saw `pam_limits` module. Should I use this module to modify `nproc` and `nofile`? If so, which domain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's actually several things you'll need to do to bump the number of filehandles up permanently. What you're attempting here is a temporary measure and only exists for as long as the shell does, it won't do it.

I've found you need to fix three things for this to be applied correctly.

The first two are related to `sysctl` and the PAM `limits.d` configuration:

```
- name: Set sysctl File Limits
  copy:
    src: 50-fs.conf
    dest: /etc/sysctl.d

- name: Set Shell File Limits
  copy:
    src: 91-nofiles.conf
    dest: /etc/security/limits.d
```

The `50-fs.conf` file looks like this:

```
fs.file-max=262144
```

The `91-nofiles.conf` file looks like this:

```
 *     soft nofile 262144
 *     hard nofile 262144
```

That takes care of the system-wide configuration. If you have a distribution using `systemd` you will need to adjust that as well:

```
- name: Set MariaDB Filehandle Limits
  notify: Reload systemctl
  copy:
    src: limits.conf
    dest: /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
```

This requires reloading `systemctl`, so you may need to add a `handler` for that:

```
- name: Reload systemctl
  shell: systemctl daemon-reload
```

The file you're copying over looks like this:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

That's taken from the example in the default service configuration file.

The final thing to do is make sure `my.cnf` or whatever stores your configuration has this directive in it:

```
open_files_limit=16384
```

You may want to add this as well:

```
open_files_limit=16384
max_connections=16384
```

You can use whatever values you think are appropriate.

Comment: Note that system limits can be set using the pam_limits module in ansible now. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pam_limits_module.html

Comment: Would be great if this answer made reference to Ansible 2.0 supporting this as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @idjaw There's four levels of limits here: System, PAM and the process launcher (e.g. `systemd`), plus the `my.cnf` application itself. I've tried to address them all here. The Ansible solution is only part of the puzzle.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for taking the time to break that down for me. Does that mean the PAM Ansible module does not make the change permanent?

Comment: @idjaw The PAM settings are an important link in the chain, but alone they aren't enough to configure MySQL with higher limits. MySQL is limited by the lowest setting in that chain, all the way back to the hard system limits.

Answer (score 28):

Since Ansible 2.0.0, [a new official module supports configuring PAM.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pam_limits_module.html)

```
# Add or modify nofile soft limit for the user joe
- pam_limits:
    domain: joe
    limit_type: soft
    limit_item: nofile
    value: 64000
```

Comment: can I combine setting multiple values in one single task using pam_limits ansible module?

Comment: sorry, the link is broken, but this one works: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pam_limits_module.html